# Perl Out of memory but there is plenty of available memory

Tags: linux, perl, memory

I am running a perl script that crashes with an Out of Memory error.
The script is running under Ubuntu Linux on a machine with 128 Gb of memory. At the time of submission most of the memory is available, however the script dies as its used memory exceeds a value slightly above 8Gb.  The machine (and the OS) are 64 bits.

I have been searching the net for limits on memory allocation in perl, but all I found is that the only limitation is the machine memory, and in this case there is plenty of that even without considering the swap partition.

This is the second time I encounter this problem. The first time I was using a different script and the same thing occurred. Does anyone have an explanation?  The only possibility I see is that perl has some limitation on memory allocation but all the results of my searches on the net seem to contradict this possibility.

Thanks in advance

**EDIT 1**:
The operating system is Fedora Linux, not Ubuntu Linux. Sorry I made confusion.

**EDIT 2**:
Here is the portion of code that leads to the error:

```
open( $psFullInput, "<", "fullPsIn.dat" );
$counter = <$psFullInput>;  # First element is counter of spectra
while ($line = <$psFullInput>)  {
  @elems = split(" ",$line);
  $xx = shift(@elems);
  $yy = shift(@elems);
  $freq = shift(@elems);
  $psStored[$xx][$yy] = [];
  push( @{$psStored[$xx][$yy]}, @elems );
}
close( $psFullInput );
```

The previous script was doing something similar, except that the array elements were not read from a file but where the result of some calculation.

**EDIT 3**:
result of perl -V:

```
 Summary of my perl5 (revision 5 version 16 subversion 3) configuration:

  Platform:
    osname=linux, osvers=3.10.9-200.fc19.x86_64, archname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi
    uname='linux buildvm-01.phx2.fedoraproject.org 3.10.9-200.fc19.x86_64 #1 smp wed aug 21 19:27:58 utc 2013 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 gnulinux '
    config_args='-des -Doptimize=-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic -Dccdlflags=-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Dlddlflags=-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches  -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro  -DDEBUGGING=-g -Dversion=5.16.3 -Dmyhostname=localhost -Dperladmin=root@localhost -Dcc=gcc -Dcf_by=Red Hat, Inc. -Dprefix=/usr -Dvendorprefix=/usr -Dsiteprefix=/usr/local -Dsitelib=/usr/local/share/perl5 -Dsitearch=/usr/local/lib64/perl5 -Dprivlib=/usr/share/perl5 -Dvendorlib=/usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl -Darchlib=/usr/lib64/perl5 -Dvendorarch=/usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl -Darchname=x86_64-linux-thread-multi -Dlibpth=/usr/local/lib64 /lib64 /usr/lib64 -Duseshrplib -Dusethreads -Duseithreads -Dusedtrace=/usr/bin/dtrace -Duselargefiles -Dd_semctl_semun -Di_db -Ui_ndbm -Di_gdbm -Di_shadow -Di_syslog -Dman3ext=3pm -Duseperlio -Dinstallusrbinperl=n -Ubincompat5005 -Uversiononly -Dpager=/usr/bin/less -isr -Dd_gethostent_r_proto -Ud_endhostent_r_proto -Ud_sethostent_r_proto -Ud_endprotoent_r_proto -Ud_setprotoent_r_proto -Ud_endservent_r_proto -Ud_setservent_r_proto -Dscriptdir=/usr/bin -Dusesitecustomize'
    hint=recommended, useposix=true, d_sigaction=define
    useithreads=define, usemultiplicity=define
    useperlio=define, d_sfio=undef, uselargefiles=define, usesocks=undef
    use64bitint=define, use64bitall=define, uselongdouble=undef
    usemymalloc=n, bincompat5005=undef
  Compiler:
    cc='gcc', ccflags ='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include -D_LARGEFILE_SOURCE -D_FILE_OFFSET_BITS=64',
    optimize='-O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic',
    cppflags='-D_REENTRANT -D_GNU_SOURCE -fno-strict-aliasing -pipe -fstack-protector -I/usr/local/include'
    ccversion='', gccversion='4.8.2 20131017 (Red Hat 4.8.2-1)', gccosandvers=''
    intsize=4, longsize=8, ptrsize=8, doublesize=8, byteorder=12345678
    d_longlong=define, longlongsize=8, d_longdbl=define, longdblsize=16
    ivtype='long', ivsize=8, nvtype='double', nvsize=8, Off_t='off_t', lseeksize=8
    alignbytes=8, prototype=define
  Linker and Libraries:
    ld='gcc', ldflags =' -fstack-protector'
    libpth=/usr/local/lib64 /lib64 /usr/lib64
    libs=-lresolv -lnsl -lgdbm -ldb -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc -lgdbm_compat
    perllibs=-lresolv -lnsl -ldl -lm -lcrypt -lutil -lpthread -lc
    libc=, so=so, useshrplib=true, libperl=libperl.so
    gnulibc_version='2.17'
  Dynamic Linking:
    dlsrc=dl_dlopen.xs, dlext=so, d_dlsymun=undef, ccdlflags='-Wl,--enable-new-dtags -Wl,-rpath,/usr/lib64/perl5/CORE'
    cccdlflags='-fPIC', lddlflags='-shared -O2 -g -pipe -Wall -Wp,-D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -fexceptions -fstack-protector --param=ssp-buffer-size=4 -grecord-gcc-switches -m64 -mtune=generic -Wl,-z,relro '


Characteristics of this binary (from libperl): 
  Compile-time options: HAS_TIMES MULTIPLICITY PERLIO_LAYERS
                        PERL_DONT_CREATE_GVSV PERL_IMPLICIT_CONTEXT
                        PERL_MALLOC_WRAP PERL_PRESERVE_IVUV USE_64_BIT_ALL
                        USE_64_BIT_INT USE_ITHREADS USE_LARGE_FILES
                        USE_LOCALE USE_LOCALE_COLLATE USE_LOCALE_CTYPE
                        USE_LOCALE_NUMERIC USE_PERLIO USE_PERL_ATOF
                        USE_REENTRANT_API USE_SITECUSTOMIZE
  Built under linux
  Compiled at Nov 11 2013 12:36:47
  %ENV:
    PERL5LIB="/home/parisia/lib/perl5/lib64/perl5"
  @INC:
    /home/parisia/lib/perl5/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/lib64/perl5
    /usr/local/share/perl5
    /usr/lib64/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/share/perl5/vendor_perl
    /usr/lib64/perl5
    /usr/share/perl5
.
```

**EDIT 4**:
Here is a short code that reproduces the problem.
As you can see, I am just filling up memory.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($xx,$yy);  # Coordinate variables
my (@elems);   # Array of elements to be stored on each matrix position

# Generate an array of 3000 floating point values.
# The list will be added to each array element. In the true script
# of course, each element has a list of completely different values.
# Here I use the same list of values for simplicity.
for ($xx = 1; $xx < 3000; $xx++)  {
  push( @elems, 1+$xx/10000 );
}

# Fill in each matrix element with the generated array
my @psStored;
for ($xx = 0; $xx < 300; $xx++)  {
  print "Row [$xx]\n";
  for ($yy = 0; $yy < 300; $yy++)  {
    push( @{$psStored[$xx][$yy]}, @elems );
  }
}
```

And this is the result of "free" just before the crash (there are some parallel processes running on the machine):

```
[parisia@gloria01 ~]$ free
             total       used       free     shared    buffers     cached
Mem:     132015788   46395504   85620284          0     217192   16979772
-/+ buffers/cache:   29198540  102817248
Swap:    268435452          0  268435452
```

**UPDATE 1**

I investigated further.  As suggested I used Devel::Size and checked the size of $psStored. The last lines of the output (printing the size at the end of each cycle in $yy) are:

```
Row [226]
8772773032
Row [227]
8811419600
Row [228]
Out of memory!
```

The size of the process when the script gives the error is:
VIRT: 8943960, RES: 8.406g

However, I tried the following script that allocates a string of a given size (in gigabytes) as specified on the command line:

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my $size = $ARGV[0];
print "$size GB ";
$size = int($size * 1000000000);
print "($size bytes)...\n";
my $var = "x" x $size;
print "Allocated\n";
```

This script has no problem with large allocations. For instance, I can request 30 GB, and I have the following output from "top" before the script finishes:
VIRT: 56.004g, RES: 0.054t

Hence, there is something that is interfering with allocation when dealing with arrays, but I do not understand what is going on.  I also tried with hashes, but I get the same limitation at around 8-9GB.

Comment: You mean GB (Bytes) not Gb (bits), right?  Can you tell us what the allocations are for that make up most of the 8 GB this script uses?  Is it a lot of small chunks or a few large ones?  Any idea how much memory it is trying to allocate at the moment it runs out?  Have you tried running in a debugger?

Comment: Try editing your question and pasting in the output of `perl -V`

Comment: @JohnZwinck
Yes Gigabytes. I think it's small chunks.  I'll edit the question to put the portion of code that gives the error.

Comment: @MarkSetchell
I added the output of perl -V

Comment: Silly question: Are you sure the user running the script does not have any limits on memory usage? This can be checked with `ulimit -a`.

Answer (score 1):

I suspect that the values of `$xx` and `$yy` are fairly large and sparse (i.e. there are big gaps between them). That would mean Perl has to create array elements for all the intervening values even though there is no data in them.

The design of the data structure depends mainly on what you want to do with it after it is built, and how you need to access it. The most space-saving way is to use a hash, so that if you have

```
$xx = 1024
$yy = 2048
```

then instead of storing the frequency in `$ps_stored[1024][2048]` (which creates `$ps_stored[0]` through to `$ps_stored[1023]`, and `$ps_stored[1024][0]` through to `$ps_stored[1024][2047]` and leaves them empty) you could store it in *hash* `$ps_stored{'1024,2048'}` which wastes no space at all.

Since you don't say anything about how you will be using this data I can't tell whether it will be workable like this, but here is some code to replace yours that builds the hash that way.

```
use strict;
use warnings;
use autodie;

my %ps_stored;

open my $ps_full_input, '<', 'fullPsIn.dat';
my $counter = <$ps_full_input>;  # First element is counter of spectra

while (<$ps_full_input>)  {
  my @elems = split;
  my ($xx, $yy, $freq) = @elems;
  push @{ $ps_stored{"$xx,$yy"} }, \@elems;
}

close $ps_full_input;
```

Note the following

- You must *always* check that an `open` call succeeded. Ignoring a failed `open` will make your program generate nonsense for no apparent reason. You can either write an explicit

  ```
  open my $ps_full_input, '<', 'fullPsIn.dat' or die $!;
  ```

  or you can `use autodie` at the top of your program, which is useful if there are more than a couple of `open` calls in your code
- You must *always* `use strict` and `use warnings` at the top of every Perl program, and declare all your variables as close as possible to their first point of use with `my`. Because your code is a sample it isn't clear whether you have `strict` and `warnings` in place, but there are no declarations at all so something is wrong
- People who are used to using Perl will thank you for using only lower-case letters, digits and underscores in local identifiers. Upper-case letters are reserved for package and module names like `Data::Dumper`
- There is no need to preset a scalar value to a reference to an empty array before you `push` onto it. An array will be *autovivified* the first time you use `push` as long as the scalar is still `undef`. For instance

  ```
  my $aref;
  push @{ $aref }, 1, 2, 3;
  ```

  has the same effect as

  ```
  my $aref;
  $aref = [];
  push @{ $aref }, 1, 2, 3;
  ```
- I have pushed a *reference* to the `@elems` array onto the `ps_stored` list. I can't tell whether particular values of `$xx` and `$yy` can occur more than once, but if they do then your way will just push all the different `@elems` sets into a single list, which could be awkward to split back into individual sets. If you push a reference instead then they remain separate

I hope this helps

Comment: Hi, thanks for you answer. What I am reading is a dense matrix: about one third of the total number of elements contains data.  The data stored in each matrix element is a list of about 3000 floating point values.  I am no expert at all for the best way of storing this kind of data, but I had already experimented with hashes and it looked as if in my case did not make much of a difference. Of course I might have done mistakes.

Comment: The code has the usual "use strict" and "use warnings" at the beginning. Indeed I am not checking for correct opening, but even with the proper checks I hit the same memory limit. All variables are correctly declared before the chunk of code I showed.

Comment: @Andrea: Okay, so you're wasting about 2/3 of your array elements, which amounts to about 25% of the memory allocated. That seems acceptable. I'd like some idea of the range of the values of `$xx` and `$yy`. You should also install [`Devel::Size`](https://metacpan.org/module/Devel::Size) and write `print total_size($psStored), "\n"` as the last statement inside the `while` loop. You may also want to print the data file line number `$.`. That way you can watch the array growing in size as you progress through the file and get some idea of the scale of the problem.

Comment: I used your suggestion but it did not give me any additional hint. I also did further investigation, and the problems appears when using either arrays or hashes. If I request a large chunk of memory then the allocation does not give any problem.  I am confused, I can't understand what is going on. I reported everything under "UPDATE 1" in the original post.

Comment: @Andrea: Have you experimented with `Devel::Size`? Have you created a sixteen-line program like mine that shows the same problem? I will help you, but I need a copy of the program and the data that is causing the *out of memory* error. If you post something on [pastebin](http://pastebin.com/) and put a link to it here then I will take a look

Answer (score 0):

OP, can you duplicate the problem with a very short test script? Maybe you can post the test script and I'll run it on my machine. Perhaps a module you didn't write is going wonky.

---

Try this code with a hash.

```
use strict;
use warnings;

my ($xx,$yy);  # Coordinate variables
my (@elems);   # Array of elements to be stored on each matrix position

# Generate an array of 3000 floating point values.
# The list will be added to each array element. In the true script
# of course, each element has a list of completely different values.
# Here I use the same list of values for simplicity.
for ($xx = 1; $xx < 3000; $xx++)  {
  push( @elems, 1+$xx/10000 );
}

# Fill in each matrix element with the generated array
my %psStored;
my $s;
$s=join('=',@elems);
for ($xx = 0; $xx < 300; $xx++)  {
  print "Row [$xx]\n";
  for ($yy = 0; $yy < 300; $yy++)  {
    $psStored{$xx,$yy} = $s; # Here I join all elements and store them as a string.
    #push( @{$psStored[$xx][$yy]}, @elems );
  }
}
```

Comment: I have edited the post and added a short code that gives me the out of memory error. As you can see I am just filling up the memory. The program gives the error after "Row [231]".

Comment: Well darn. I got an out of memory error also after it printed "Row [139]". I'm on Linux RHEL 5.5.56 with Perl 5.8.8.

Comment: That is interesting! So there IS a problem, isn't there?

Comment: I used a hash of strings instead and put new code above. Try it. I got no error using a 2D hash.

Comment: Yes, this actually works. Nice, I could then work on each string as needed!  However still the question holds. Why do I hit a limit at about 8Gb?  Is there some limit in the amount of memory that can be used by a perl process?  It looks as if there **is** a limit.